# NulPointerException при создании объекта URL для работы с удалённым сервером Redis

Tags: java, intellij-idea, redis

В Intellij IDEA в проекте MAVEN пытаюсь подключиться к удалённому серверу Redis.
В файле redis_url.txt находится информация о сервере в виде строки:`redis://redistogo:648....@pike.redistogo.com:1...9/`
Сам файл расположен в директории `src/main/resources` проекта. `resources` помечен как `Test Resources Root`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В процессе создания объекта `redis.client.jedis.Jedis`, предоставленным в книге Аллен Б.Доуни "Алгоритмы и структуры данных" кодом, используя данные файла `redis_url.txt`, создаётся объект java.net.URL. Проблема возникла именно на этом этапе. Код `URL fileURL = JedisMaker.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filename);` возвращает `null`. Соответственно в следующей строке `NullPointerException`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, почему такой результат и как исправить?
Возможно не правильно указан путь к файлу, но 5 строчек тестового кода выше (`File file = new File(filename); ...`) свидетельствуют о том, что файл доступен по этому адресу.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что resource это не file.
Ваш файл может быть доступен по имени `/redis_url.txt`, так как он лежит непосредственно в директории `src/main/resources`, а maven перекладывает все файлы из этой директории в директорию `target/classes`, в которой java ищет ресурсы.
А его содержимое можно будет прочитать из входного потока, который можно получить следующим образом: `InputStream inputStream = JedisMaker.class.getResourceAsStream("/redis_url.txt");`